# how to recieve a generic json string on the controller using spring mvc

Tags: java, json, spring

hi I would like to receive a generic json string  on the spring controller , this "generic string " will represent different´s types of object´s send by other system .. at this moment I would like to have one only entry point to receive all posts .

I have seem several example , but all of them receive one specific json object like car student user and so on ....

Thank you all
Roque

Comment: *I would like, I want....*, you're just telling us your requirements, but *what* have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to receive specific objects with spring. You can also receive a plain string, which in your case would be a "generic string".

An example of receiving a plain string:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public void test(@RequestBody String test){
    //The rest of your code
}
```

Comment: one could argue, that receiving a `String` as a body, might be overkill

Comment: @lino I completely agree and you really shouldn't receive strings like this. The best practice is to have a endpoint per object and not a "generic" endpoint. But OP asked for something where he can post everything to.